# The technique which deletes an execution file itself and a folder includes it

Tags: c#, directory, delete-file

I am developing the program which deletes the execution file itself for a uninstaller. Because it was the theme frequently taken up also at this site, I found the way easily.

One of answer is->http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31454/How-To-Make-Your-Application-Delete-Itself-Immedia. I referred to this and wrote it.

```
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.FileName = "cmd";
psi.Arguments = "/C rmdir /s /q \"" + dir + "\"";
Process p = Process.Start(psi);
Application.Exit();
```

Deleting its file was succeeded, on the other hand, the folder was not deleted. Although I would like to also delete a folder including it, are there any good ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use rmdir to delete the current directory, as per [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rmdir.mspx?mfr=true). I haven't tried the technique myself at all... but perhaps navigate up a directory then try again?

Comment: It was successful when changing the current directory based on your opinion. Thanks.

psi.Arguments = "/C cd .. & rmdir /s /q \"" + dir + "\"";